# Reading epub using MKWebView failed with message "WebFilterIsActive returning: NO"

Tags: ios, swift, epub

I am using xcode 11.5 and ios 13.5.1 and I am trying to read "epub" files located locally in my project using MKWebView as follow :

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webConfiguration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true

let webView = WKWebView(frame: vc.view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)

if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "epub")  {

    if url.isFileURL {
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        vc.view.addSubview(webView)
    } else {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

However, the page does not load "epub" file and instead, it gives me the following error :

```
> WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
> 
> WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

What's the problem with my solution? Is there any alternative ways to read epub files ?

Answer (score 0):

[An epub file](https://ebookflightdeck.com/handbook/zipping) is a zip file with some html, styles, and metadata.

To make an app that can read an epub you should with an unzipping library which may require you to rename the file first.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636207/unzipping-epub-in-swift) is a thread that might be helpful